# Non zero function on a set.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Let M be a set with a binary operation ○. Now, define addition on MxM to be (a,b) + (c,d) = (a○c,b○d).

Is there a general function f from MxM to itself such that
f((a○c,b○d)) is not equal to f((a,b)) ○ f((c,d)) for two nonzero ordered pairs?

Comment: What do you mean by a "general function"?  And what do you mean by "nonzero"?

Comment: As the question is, the answer is no. Let $M$ be the empty set. But surely you have more structure in mind. You use the term "nonzero," which certainly doesn't make sense for every set with a binary operation.

Comment: When I say an element is nonzero, I just mean it is not the ordered pair (e,e) where m○e = e○m = m for all m in M.

Comment: For example, I know if f((a,b)) = (a○k,b) for some k in M not equal to e, then f((a○c,b○d)) + (k,e) = f(a,b) + f(c,d). So that would be a general function that would satisfy my criteria, but what are some others?

Comment: You failed to mention that it has an identity. Certainly this is not a requirement for a set with a binary operation. And you write it as addition, which suggests that it is commutative and associative. Are there inverses? Are you just talking about abelian groups?